# Como mandar datos con ajax para no tener que recargar la pagina para que salgan los cambios?

Tags: php, ajax

Que tal, tengo un botón AGREGAR, que contiene dos campos, los cuales se llenan y se envían los datos a la tabla en mysql y en la tabla debajo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al dar click en GUARDAR para enviar los datos me sale este mensaje, pero me lo manda a otra pagina, como le hago para que salga en la misma ventana del modal?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y tengo que volver a la pagina y actualizar para que me aparezcan los datos, lo cual es molesto, quiero que se haga en automático, me dijeron que con ajax, pero no se como, apenas empiezo y no se utilizarlo
que necesito, alguna librería? Ojala me puedan ayudar

Les dejo mi código de mi modal

```html
<!-- Modal-->
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="agregarModal_validacion.php">
<div id="myModal1" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content"> 
      <!--Cabecera del modal-->
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Nuevo Trabajo</h4>
      </div> 
      <!--Contenido del modal-->
      <div class="modal-body">
      
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-xm-6">
          <input class="form-control" type="text" id="txt_nombre" name="txt_nombre" placeholder="Nombre del trabajo" required="">
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-xm-6">
          <input class="form-control " type="text" id="txt_costo" name="txt_costo" placeholder="Costo" required="">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div> 
      <!--Final del modal-->
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" style="width: 100%;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></span> Guardar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Y el codigo de mi php que hace la consulta

```html
<?
$conexion= mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "registros");
if($conexion)
{


  //Variables
  
  $Nombre_Trabajo = $_POST['txt_nombre'];
  $Costo=$_POST['txt_costo'];


//realiza la consulta
  $consulta= "INSERT INTO trabajos (Nombre_Trabajo, Costo) values ('$Nombre_Trabajo','$Costo')";
  
  

//para ejecutar consulta
  $resultado=mysqli_query($conexion ,$consulta);
 
  if ($resultado) 
  { 
    $messages[]  = "Los datos han sido agregados correctamente";
  }
    
  else 
  {
    $errors[]= "No se puedo realizar la accion";
  } 
      
if (isset($errors)){
      
      ?>
      <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="consulta_lista.php">&times;</button>
          <strong>Error!</strong> 
          <?php
            foreach ($errors as $error) {
                echo $error;
              }
            ?>
      </div>
      <?php
      }

if (isset($messages)){
        
        ?>
        <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="myModal1">&times;</button>
            <strong>¡Bien hecho!</strong>
            <?php
              foreach ($messages as $message) {
                  echo $message;
                }
              ?>
        </div>
        <?php
      }

  

}
  else{ 
        echo ""; 
      }
        mysqli_close($conexion);   
      ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Para que esto no ocurra la forma mas logica es que tu modal no sea un `<form>` y asi ahorrar el `submit`de tu boton una vez que hagas click en el boton llamas al `ajax` y en `success` actualizas los valores que recibes de la respuesta de tu `ajax`

El click del boton ahora debe funcionar con jquery

Boton

```
<button id="guardar" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" style="width: 100%;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></span> Guardar</button>
```

Click

```
$('#guardar').click(function(){
       var parametros = {
            "nombre" : $("#txtNombre").val(),
            "costo" : $("#txtCosto").val()
      }
      $.ajax({
              data : parametros,
              url : "agregarModal_validacion.php"
              type : "post"
              success : function(response){
                     //response contiene la respuesta al llamado de tu archivo
                     //aqui actualizas los valores de inmediato llamando a sus respectivas id.
              }
       })
});
```

Debes modificar la respuesta de tu archivo PHP y dejarla como `JSON`

Comment: Muchas gracias, pero como llamo al ajax? no se

Comment: Edite mi respuesta.

Comment: eso de que dices que modifique la respuesta en el php, te refieres a la consulta?

Comment: No amigo! La consulta esta todo correcto! Pero ajax trabaja con formato Json! Y debes comprender que cuando se hace una llamada esta entrega una respuesta. En tu caso tu hacer un nuevo insert en tu tabla y tambien quieres actualizar los valores en tu lista!. Lamentablemente no estoy en un computador como para darte un ejemplo mas completo pero te dejo un link interesante donde podras comprender mas de Ajax y Php. https://www.google.cl/amp/s/cybmeta.com/ajax-con-json-y-php-ejemplo-paso-a-paso/amp?client=safari

Answer (score 2):

Es muy facil su implementación, en primer lugar debes eliminar tu `action` de la etiqueta `form` de tu formulario y segundo lugar debes crear una caja para obtener la respuesta `AJAX`.

*Ejemplo:*

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="POST">
   <!-- Tus inputs -->
</form>

<div id="respuesta"><!-- Respuesta AJAX --></div>
```

En la misma página que tu formulario debes añadir el `AJAX`

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $(document).on('submit', '#form1', function() { 

        //Obtenemos datos formulario.
        var data = $(this).serialize(); 

        //AJAX.
        $.ajax({  
            type : 'POST',
            url  : 'agregarModal_validacion.php',
            data:  data, 

            success:function(data) {  
                $('#respuesta').html(data).fadeIn();
            }  
        });
        return false;
   });
});//Fin document.
```

> **Nota:** importante añadir la *librería de `jQuery`* en tu documento `HTML`, lo suyo seria entre la etiqueta `<head></head>`

*Ejemplo Completo:*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang ="es-ES">
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){   
         $(document).on('submit', '#form1', function() { 

              //Obtenemos datos formulario.
              var data = $(this).serialize(); 

              //AJAX.
              $.ajax({  
                 type : 'POST',
                 url  : 'agregarModal_validacion.php',
                 data:  data, 

                 success:function(data) {  
                     $('#respuesta').html(data).fadeIn();
                 }  
              });
              return false;
        });
      });//Fin document.
    </script>        
</head>
<body>
   <!-- tu formulario -->
   <form id="form1" name="form1" method="POST">
      <!-- Tus inputs -->
   </form>

   <div id="respuesta"><!-- Respuesta AJAX --></div>
</body>
</html>
```

*agregarModal_validacion.php*

Sigues con tu código `PHP`, es importante que el archivo `PHP` coincida con la `URL` del `AJAX`.

Answer (score 1):

El modal deja el formulario y quita submit por button, en ella le agregas un id y ya con el Jquery lo haces:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#idTuboton").click(function () {
   var data = form.serialize();
   $.post('urlDetuPhp',data,function (data) {
       $('#respuesta').html(data);
    });
 });
});
```

Boton:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" style="width: 100%;" id="idTuboton><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></span> Guardar</button>
```

Ya simplemente es acomodarlo a su gusto y en el archivo php hacer el insert, eso si, haz un alert del data para que veas como se envía... Ya el resto pues es un poco de imaginacion y autodidacta...